# How to calculate lim n × sin(1/(n^2)) when n goes to +infinity

Tags: limits

I found this problem:

$ \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} n \sin \left( \frac{1}{n^2} \right)$

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

$$n\sin(\frac{1}{n^2})=\frac 1n\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n^2})}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Or use the inequality

$$(\forall X\in\Bbb R)\; \; |\sin(X)|\le |X|$$
to get

$$(\forall n>0)\; |n\sin(\frac{1}{n^2})|\le \frac 1n$$

So, your limit is zero.

Comment: Is the equality true for cosine

Comment: So how i can solve this limit ?

Comment: Lim n^2 × cos(1/n^4) × sin (1/n^3) at +infinity